# Can we limit the throughput of a luigi Task?

Tags: python, spotify, luigi

We have a Luigi Task that request a piece of information from a 3rd party service. We are limited on the number of call requests we can perform per minute to that API call.

Is there a way to specify on a per-Task basis how many tasks of this kind must the scheduler run per unit of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We implemented our own rate limiting in the task. Our API limit was low enough that we could saturate it with a single thread. When we received a rate limit response, we just back off and retry.

One thing you can do is to declare the API call as a [resource](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#resources-config). You can set how many of the resource is available in the config, and then how many of the resource the task consumes as a [property on the task](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.task.html?highlight=resources#luigi.task.Task.resources). This will then limit you to running n of that task at a time.

in config:

```
[resources]
api=1
```

in code for Task:

```
resources = {"api": 1}
```